# Padronização PHP Fig Namespaces

Tags: php, namespace

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP com meu framework mvc e segue o seguinte modelo:

```
Namespace         Diretorio                              Desc
Nautilus\         root/Nautilus/src/Nautilus_Web/        Aplicação principal
Nautilus\Service  root/Nautilus/src/Nautilus_Service/    Serviços
Nautilus\Domain   root/Nautilus/src/Nautilus_Domain/     Modelos e repositórios
```

Estou padronizando meu projeto de acordo com o PHP-Fig e conforme a documentação o namespace deve corresponder ao diretório fisico.

Me pergunto se a padronização está sendo feita da forma errada já que o Nautilus\Service e Nautilus\Domain deveriam incluir as classes a partir do diretório do namespace Nautilus que seria:

**root/Nautilus/src/Nautilus_Web/....**

Se meu namespace chama Nautilus o diretório fisico deveria ser:

`root/Nautilus/src/Nautilus_Web/Nautilus` não? ou então renomear o namespace para `Nautilus\Web` dai o diretório .../src/Nautilus_Web corresponderia, correto?

Obrigado!

Comment: Qual padrão você está implementado, psr-4 ou psr-0 ?

Comment: Estou implementando todos PSR-0 ao PSR-4!

Comment: psr-4 sobrepõe psr-0, logo por que você implementar ambos?

Comment: A PSR-4 não sobrepõe tudo apenas redefine algumas especificações!

Comment: @gmsantos Você está certo, na descrição da PS4 fala que é uma melhora nas definições mas redefine tudo sem exceção!

Comment: redefine tudo sem exceção? Errado. na psr-0, `_` são convertidos para diretórios, o que não acontece na psr-4 por exemplo: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

Comment: Na PSR0 o _ era convertido em diretórios, conforme você falou, na PSR4 o _ é tratado como parte do namespace logo a atribuição dada ao _ foi redefinida. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito estar vendo três perguntas então vou respondê-las na ordem que faz mais sentido: Estrutura de diretórios, namespaces e conteúdo.

Como todo framework ou componente/biblioteca, seja ele proprietário ou 3rd-Party é costume, independente da PSR, a partir do diretório raiz se ter um subdiretório normalmente chamado **vendor** e, dentro dele, um diretório para cada recurso:

```
|-\
| |-\Application
|   |-\Application\Portal
|      |-\Application\Portal\Models
|      |-\Application\Portal\Views
|      |-\Application\Portal\Controllers
|   |-\Application\Portal
|      |-\Application\Admin\Models
|      |-\Application\Admin\Views
|      |-\Application\Admin\Controllers
| |-\vendor
|   |-\vendor\Symfony
|   |-\vendor\Doctrine
|   |-\vendor\Nautilus
```

Namespaces de frameworks ou bibliotecas/componentes fogem um pouco à regra de serem iniciados a partir do diretório-raiz principalmente por conta dos autoloaders os quais quase sempre levam em conta o *include_path* que deve [ser modificado](http://www.php.net/set_include_path) em tempo de execução para incluir, dentre o que você precisar, esse diretório **vendor**:

```
set_include_path(
    '.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . realpath( './vendor' )
);
```

Por fim, o localização do conteúdo. Uma vez que você resolva os dois problemas acima, você resolve esse último também pois todo *autoloader* deve trabalhar a partir do diretório-raiz e como o **vendor** já faz parte do *include_path* toda vez que você instanciar uma nova classe ou importar um recurso (com *use*), contanto que este ainda não tenha sido declarado no escopo do invocador (senão não há intervenção do autoloader) você estará sempre "posicionado" na rai\ da Aplicação.

Ou seja, imagine que `Nautilus\Web\Domain` precise de algum recurso de `Nautilus\Web\Service`. Mesmo que abos estiejam em diretórios completamente separados, ambos estarão sob as asas do mesmo namespace-pai, **Nautilus**

Ah! E a propósito, com exceção da modificação do *include_path*, esqueça do conceito de caminhos relativos. ;)